# $eval validate if inserted variable doesnt exists/incorrect

Tags: html, angularjs, eval

In my app i need to allow the user to add their own math formulas, can use operators and call variables. There is anyway to validate if a user write wrong a variable or a unknown variable to show an error?
I have and example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQqR31WoDQ7UX9d2rHz1?p=preview), you have some scope variables in the top of the controller. A minor difference, if I insert an invalid variable in the example it shows `null`, but in my code appears in blank.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well honestly, if you weren't lazily throwing this stuff in eval, you could easily parse it yourself I recon.

How about removing all whitespaces, and interating over every single character?
I mean as long as there are no variables like aa or ab, you can just check like.

```
for (var i = 0; i < answer.length ; i++) {
    if (!isvalidParamOrOperator(answer[i])) {
        //can show error at position i+1;
        return false;
    } 
}
```

with isValidParamOrOperator being something like

```
function(str) {
    return "1234567890ab".indexOf(str);
}
```

Of course it becomes a little bit more complicated at longer params, but you'd be able to create something that splits on all operators like + - spaces & numbers. And then you'll have a list of all params which you can check. which should probably be checked on an array instead of my current suggestion, but this shouldn't be hard after you implement something like this.

Comment: Nice, didnt tought that way, my variables belong to an object called item, then it has their own params, like item.price, item.workflow etc.

Comment: I guess you could get there by by using my suggestions.